# Evaluating integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + c^2}} e^{-(x-m)^2} dx$ and one more similar

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, special-functions

I'm trying to evaluate two integrals:
$$f(m,c) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + c^2}} e^{-(x-m)^2} dx$$
and
$$g(m,c) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + c^2}} e^{-(x-m)^2} dx$$
where $c,m\in\mathbb{R}$

For $f(m,c)$ I was trying to substitute $x$ with $t = \sqrt{x^2 + c^2}$, which eliminates the fraction, but complicates the expression under the exponent. Also, I'm not sure what the new limits of integration should be:
$$f(m,c) = \int_{?}^{?} e^{-(\sqrt{t^2-c^2}-m)^2} dt$$
Maybe [this integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47708/evaluating-int-1-infty-exp-x2n-x-b2-mathrm-dx) is related, but I couldn't bring $f(m,c)$ to it.

For $g(m,c)$ I've tried to substitute $x$ with $x=c\sinh{t}$, which leads to integral:
$$g(m,c) = \int_{?}^{?} e^{-(c\sinh{t}-m)^2} dt$$
with which I don't know what to do next.
Maybe [this integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008325/evaluate-the-integral-int-mathbb-r-frac-exp-left-yx2z-cdot-x-sqrtx2?rq=1) is related to $g(m,c)$.

Comment: Something that will save you hard work later: note that $e^{m^2}g=\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{e^{-x^2}e^{2mx}}{\sqrt{x^2+c^2}}dx$, so $e^{m^2}f=\frac12\partial_m(e^{m^2}g)$, i.e. $f=mg+\frac12\partial_mg$.

Answer (score 2):

If $m$ is "small" you could expand the exponential term as
$$e^{-(x-m)^2}=e^{-x^2}\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(x)\, m^n$$ where the first polynomials are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & P_n(x) \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 x \\
 2 & 2 x^2-1 \\
 3 & \frac{4 x^3}{3}-2 x \\
 4 & \frac{2 x^4}{3}-2 x^2+\frac{1}{2} \\
 5 & \frac{4 x^5}{15}-\frac{4 x^3}{3}+x \\
 6 & \frac{4 x^6}{45}-\frac{2 x^4}{3}+x^2-\frac{1}{6} \\
 7 & \frac{8 x^7}{315}-\frac{4 x^5}{15}+\frac{2 x^3}{3}-\frac{x}{3} \\
 8 & \frac{2 x^8}{315}-\frac{4 x^6}{45}+\frac{x^4}{3}-\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{1}{24} \\
 9 & \frac{4 x^9}{2835}-\frac{8 x^7}{315}+\frac{2 x^5}{15}-\frac{2
   x^3}{9}+\frac{x}{12} \\
 10 & \frac{4 x^{10}}{14175}-\frac{2 x^8}{315}+\frac{2
   x^6}{45}-\frac{x^4}{9}+\frac{x^2}{12}-\frac{1}{120} \\
 11 & \frac{8 x^{11}}{155925}-\frac{4 x^9}{2835}+\frac{4 x^7}{315}-\frac{2
   x^5}{45}+\frac{x^3}{18}-\frac{x}{60} \\
 12 & \frac{4 x^{12}}{467775}-\frac{4 x^{10}}{14175}+\frac{x^8}{315}-\frac{2
   x^6}{135}+\frac{x^4}{36}-\frac{x^2}{60}+\frac{1}{720}
\end{array}
\right)$$

and use
$$I_{2n}= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{\sqrt{x^2 + c^2}} e^{-x^2}\, dx$$ and face linear combinations of Bessel functions